# How can load sample html page on index page in Play framework?

Tags: java, frameworks, playframework, playframework-2.0, javabeans

here is my piece code:

```
 <div id="account"><a href="@routes.Contacts.blank()">Contact</a></div>`
```

instead of it, i use above code

`<div id="account"><a href="account.html">Contact</a></div>`

So, i want to direct load static html page on index page.
Please help me. 
Tank's

Comment: You can post your code - simply copy & paste )

Comment: you can. while post editing check help icon for ways of code formatting. Please, improve your question or it will be closed/removed soon

Comment: i need define route of that html page?

Comment: You need to read this [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) =)

Answer (score 10):

You can map the index page to a static file by creating a route in your `conf/routes` file, like:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
GET     /*file                      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a route in `conf/routes` file pointing some action ie:

```
GET  /contact    controllers.Contacts.blank
```

so then you can build links with typed routes (strongly recommended):

```
<a href="@routes.Contacts.blank()">Contact</a>
```

or you can write it as a hardcoded path. What's important - it MUST fit second part of your route in the final HTML code

You can also write routes with `*.html` 'extension' BUT it's completely unnecessary as browsers recognizes response by its header not the path!

```
GET  /contact.html    controllers.Contacts.blank
```